# ASP.NET Configuration Won't Open

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-application-project

I can't imagine why it won't open!

I've check the issue which could be causing this and they are

1. not having login control
2. placing my project in directory with complicated symbols or sth like that and my project dir is clean "C:\Documents and Settings\Shak\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication1"

What else could it be!!

Comment: On clicking the menu, does VS start ASP.NET development web server and open browser?

Comment: just the web server but it doesn't open the browser

Comment: I think or I don't think .. actually I'm sure but I'm shocked of such a lame bug! .. you see the spaces in my WebAppliction dir .. this is what's causing the problem !! .. I tried to place it in D:/WebAppliction1 it worked :S really soo lame MS!!

Comment: @IKashef, the config web application is located in .NET Fx directory e.g. `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles`. All you need is to create a web site for the same and then launch it in browser using url such as `<web site name>/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=<physical path to your project root dir>`. So you can probably use this method to edit config even if you have spaces in your physical path.

Comment: @IKashef I doubt it, that that is the main reason. Standard Visual Studio uses the "My documents"-folder to store the projects, so there are allways spaces in the path and then nobody could run their app. Allthough I have no idea what's causing this.

Comment: @VinayC- I'm sorry! I didn't quiet get you, could you break it up for me !?

Comment: @Koen- I've tried it by experimentally that's why I'm saying so lame! that's what I'm saying :S! "My documents" is the default chosen by them! check this one http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/465576/unable-to-view-asp-net-configuration-page-from-vs-2010-in-windows-7-rc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be the white-space in the project name. After removing these, it all worked fine.

Comment: Well, if you think otherwise then let us know the right answer.
 just down-voting without any explanation reflects your negative attitude.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this problem with VS2010 and FireFox.

What works for me is to make sure the project is running in Debug mode (F5).

It seems counter-intuitive but it works.